# My list component disappears when I navigate away and back to a tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am using React Navigation v2 for my React Native app and am using a tab navigator. The main tab (a feed of posts) looks like so when it [first renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sq6p.jpg). After selecting one of the two other tabs and then navigating back to my main tab, it looks [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGrcH.jpg). For some reason, the input bar is rendering just fine, but the list disappears until I post again. Then the feed list (including the new post) will appear on screen.

In the componentDidMount() lifecycle method, I call an action called fetchFeed() that pulls all the feed data from a firebase database and saves it to state (which is then mapped to props with redux). The renderFeed() method is called in the render() method and organizes the feedData in a List component (from nativebase).

I'm unsure as to why the input bar renders when the list does not, but I've made the assumption that I need to trigger some state change, like calling the fetchFeed() method again, when I navigate back to the main tab.

So far I have tried using the navigationEvents feature from React Navigation to run a method when the user navigates back, but even simply trying to console log with this feature like so:

```
<NavigationEvents
  onWillFocus={payload => {
  console.log("will focus", payload);
  }}
/>
```

throws the error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string..."

I don't know what to try next...I'd really appreciate any help/advice you can give! Code is below:

```
class FeedScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Announcements',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchFeed(this.props.organization);
    this.registerForPushNotifications();
  }

  renderFeed = () => {
    const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    const listKey = `${random}${this.props.loadingList}`;
    if (this.props.loadingList) {
      return <Spinner />;
    } else if (this.props.error) {
      return (<Text>{this.props.error}</Text>);
    } return (
      <List
        key={listKey}
        enableEmptySections
        dataArray={this.props.feedData}
        renderRow={this.renderPost}
        keyExtractor={(post) => post.key}
      />
    );
  }

    .
    .
 //several unrelated methods
    .
    .

    render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <View style={styles.messageBoxContainer}>
            <Input
              onChangeText={this.props.postChanged.bind(this)}
              value={this.props.postContent}
              style={styles.messageBox}
              multiline
            />
            {this.renderButton()}
          </View>
          {this.renderFeed()}
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

    .
    .
    .
//styles object and mapStateToProps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I set up a `willFocus` listener for React Navigation v2

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.willFocus);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.willFocusSubscription) {
      this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
  }
}

willFocus = (payload) => {
  // do stuff here 
}
```

I’m not sure why your list is disappearing. Could the feedData be getting set to an empty array?

Comment: This worked! Thank you. 

You were right, the feedData array was undefined when navigating back to the tab. Still not sure why, but calling the 'fetchFeed()' action from the willFocus method you provided solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should register push notifications in your constructor.

Look at this link for a much more detailed example:
https://www.pubnub.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications-ios-android/